# Idea run/debug py.test single test not the whole suite

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pytest

I'm creating a python test suite (using py.test). I'm coding the tests in Idea and I don't know how to debug a single test.

[image]

This is my setting of the debugger. It runs the whole testsuite. So I have to run all the tests before it gets to the one I'm trying to debug.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your configuration, set:

- Target to the relative path of one of your test files, i.e. `testsuite/psa/test_psa_integration.py`
- Keywords to a keyword that identifies the test you are trying to run specifically. If tests are part of a class, Keywords should be something like: `TestPsaIntegration and test_psa_integration_example`

I don't use IntelliJ, but in PyCharm, you can easily debug tests without going through this tedious process of adding a Run/Debug configuration each time.

To do this with PyCharm, go to:
`Preferences (or Settings) > Tools > Python Integrated Tools` and set `Default test runner` to `py.test`.

Then, back in your file (i.e. `test_psa_integration.py`), you could just right-click anywhere **within** the code of a test, and select either `Run 'py.test in ...'` or `Debug 'py.test in...'` which will automatically create a new Run/Debug configuration as explained previously.

Comment: I noticed that when pytest copies the original pytest configuration it loses some settings, like environment variables and relative path. Even if I set up a default pytest configuration, when I run the single script it will ignore the default settings. Super annoying. This is a problem especially for remote interpreters.

Comment: For this to work for me I had to add the folder with the tests to `pytest.ini`.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is adding `--no-cov --capture=no` into *Additional Arguments*. To make this automatic for other test file, add those into the *Template* part.